# Finding latent variables in 7 dichotomous variables

Tags: spss, multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, references, binary-data

I have read other posts on conducting Factor analysis (FA) with dichotomous variables and although it appears clear that FA done in the default way is not appropriate, I am still unclear about a few things.

I have 7 variables that are yes/no responses. They are assessing peoples functioning (e.g., working yes/no, involvement with justice system yes/no etc). I want to combine these responses to have two variables that represent domains of functioning (e.g., occupational and social). I suspect three of them will be occupational and 4 of them social. I would like to do something analogous to a FA to confirm this.

I only have access to SPSS (and am only familiar with this package) so am looking for advice on how to do this with SPSS.

Do I do a FA with tetrachoric correlations instead of Pearsons (how is this done?)? Or can I do Latent Trait Analysis in SPSS?

I am specifically looking for references with step-by-step instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably recommend the LCA route. Penn State's Methodology Center has a standalone program that I believe is free you can use to analyze the data (WinLTA). I have used their LCA/LTA analysis package for SAS and have found it to be quite good.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the (free) R Essentials for SPSS Statistics (available from the SPSS Community site at www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral via the Downloads for SPSS Statistics link, you get the STATS LATENT CLASS command and associated dialog box for it.